# How to call server side function using jQuery in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am beginner in jQuery.

I want to know that as we can call server side method in ASP.Net by javascript using XMLHttpRequest object and GET verb, similarly can we call the same using jQuery $get()  or we are able to do it by POST onley?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use any of;

- $.get();
- $.post();
- $.ajax();

Comment: Thanks Matt,Can you give a sort example ?

Comment: Assuming that by "server side method" you are talking about a method marked WebMethod in your asp.net page, or a web service

Comment: Here's a little tute: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Sorry miss spell in comment. I wnat to say can you give a short example ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing tute. But it explains about the POST type of call. What i want to know that similarly can we do the same by GET ?

Comment: Yes, just change the "POST" to "GET"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4378/discussion-between-prateek-deshpande-and-matt-tew)

Comment: i went for same but it calls function in "error:" part with status 500.

Comment: This is what i have written in aspx page  <br /> $.ajax( { type: "GET", url: "AjaxSample.aspx/Greet", data: "{}", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json", success: function(msg) { debugger; $('div').val(data); }, error: function(err) { debugger; $('div').val('Error'); }